# asymptotic density of zeros for these bessel functions?

Tags: bessel-functions

Is there an asymptotic formula for the number of zeros for Bessel functions $J_{ix}(ia)$ and $K_{x}(a)$?

Where $x$ is the dependent variable and $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.